# Error when trying to override create method in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

iam trying to override the create method in lumen, i used the exact same code in laravel and worked like a charm, but when i try it in lumen i get memory size error, here's my code:

**web.php:**

```
$app->get('/test', function () {
    User::create(['name'=>'a','email'=>'sd.sd@ds.com']);
});
```

**User.php:**

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::create($attributes);
}
```

as you can see nothing special here, here's the full error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in \vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes.php on line 176

by the way, i tried increasing memory size allowed, and commenting and uncommenting fillable array but nothing worked ....

Comment: Try `**return**
 parent::create($attributes);` - I have no idea about lumen nor laravel though

Comment: @Xatenev didn't work sadly

Comment: I feel like there's important parts of the code that you're not sharing

Comment: this is everything i wrote after installation of the framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

You can increase your **memory_limit** from (`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`), after you may need to restart your server

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

or

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Hmmm... I know nothing about Laravel but, do you think 1GB of RAM is not enough to create what appears to be a simple entity with a couple of attributes?

Comment: I tried that and it wasn't enough, seems like there's a memory leak somehwere i don't know

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem due to lumen rejecting mass assignment. Can you try by adding the guarded field in your User.php

```
protected $guarded = [];
```